# Error while processing the servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have the following JSP File and Servlet file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>ABC Corporation</title>
    <h1>Terminal Login</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="login" action="/WebAccount/LoginServlet?" method="post" />
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
    Password: <input type="text" name="password" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN"/>

    Not User? Register Here: <input type="submit" action="/WebAccount/register.jsp" value="REGISTER">

</body>
</html>
```

Servlet Code:

```
class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /** 
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String username = request.getParameter("Username").toString();
        String password = request.getParameter("Password").toString();
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/account";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "school");

            Statement statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from Users where username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "';");
            String user;
            String pass;

            while (rs.next()) {
                user = rs.getString(username).toString();
                pass = rs.getString(password).toString();

                if (username.equals(user) && password.equals(pass)) {
                    response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
                    conn.close();
                }
            }
            if (!rs.next()) {
                out.println("Login failed");
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
             throw new ServletException("Cannot Connect", ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new ServletException("Login failed", ex);

        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

I am getting this error while processing the servlet:

java.lang.NullPointerException

```
LoginServlet.processRequest(LoginServlet.java:38)
LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:104)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Any mistakes?

Comment: Is that the whole of LoginServlet.java, or have you removed some lines?  Which of the lines in the code you posted is line 38 of the original file?

Comment: This one,
 String username = request.getParameter("username");

Comment: That line can impossibly throw a `NullPointerException` in this context. You edited too much or you are not running the code you think you're running.

Comment: @BalusC error has gone, but I am getting a blank screen..:(

Comment: Oh? So the initial problem was solved and the question was *actually* answered? Why did you edit the initial question into a completely different question instead of asking a new question? I'll rollback your confusing edits. You need to ask a new question about your new problem.

Comment: @BalusC
please have a look on updated servlet code, it's giving me a blank screen now.

Comment: As said, that's a **different** problem. You do not get the `NullPointerException` anymore, right? Your initial problem is solved. You have now a completely different, new and independent problem. You should ask a new question for that by pressing `Ask Question` button on right top. You should not edit an existing question about something entirely different for that. That's not how it works here. It would make all existing answers utterly worthless and confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly at which line the exception is thrown. Read the error message. It contains useful information.

I can tell you just by examining the code that this line will cause an exception since the input field is named `username` (lowercase u), and you read the (thus null) parameter `Username` (uppercase U):

```
String username = request.getParameter("Username").toString();
```

BTW, why are you calling `toString()` on a `String`?

Comment: I can't tell from looking at his code exactly where line 38 is.  That's the first thing we need to ascertain. IMHO .. PSM

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is at "LoginServlet.java, line 38"?  It looks like "out" might be null?

If the problem is indeed with the response "writer" object, here's one possible explanation:

> http://www.coderanch.com/t/484052/Tomcat/Tomcat-Returning-NullPointer-upon-closing
>
> Thanks The problem was response.getWriter() object was declared as
>   global in servlet, so it became common to all threads. and if one
>   thread closes it, it used to give NullPtrException in other threads.

Comment: `out` is already been declared inside the same method block, so that can't be it.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>    at LoginServlet.processRequest(LoginServlet.java:38)

Just read the 1st line of the trace. Something at line 38 of `LoginServlet` class, inside the `processRequest()` method, is `null` while your code didn't expect it to be.

Well, I'll try my magic ball. You declared the 2 input fields as follows:

```html
Username: <input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
Password: <input type="text" name="password" value=""/>
```

So, with the parameter names `username` and `password` respectively.

However, you're attempting to access it as follows:

```java
String username = request.getParameter("Username").toString();
String password = request.getParameter("Password").toString();
```

Note the uppercased 1st character! This does not match. The `getParameter()` would return `null` here and the (unnecessary btw) `toString()` call on `null` will cause a `NullPointerEXception`.

Fix it accordingly:

```java
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
```

For some more hints about using servlets, you may find our [servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) useful as well.